# Simple htaccess rewrite stops at questionmark?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a very simple Apache rewrite rule that is not working.

I want to rewrite from example.com/something/123 to example.com/something.php?id=123

If I use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^something/(.*)$ something.php?id=$1
```

The htaccess tester at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ sends the example URL to just example.com/something.php without the variable. If I replace the questionmark in the rule with something else (for example a dash -) the rule correctly rewrites to example.com/something.php-id=123.

So clearly the questionmark is something special, but every simple example I find seem to be doing exactly the same as I am doing?? I am missing something very obvious here I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Have your rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^something/([^/]+)/?$ something.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

And don't rely on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ as that is not very reliable for testing reliable rules.